# Scala function definition vs application

Tags: scala

Why does f in the following code snippet gives the value of 1. I was expected `f()` to be 1. How can I obtain a reference to the function `f:()=> Int`

```
var y = 0
def f():Int = {y + 1}

f
```

Somethings in scala drive me nuts.

Comment: `f` returns `Int` as per your definition

Comment: One of the many [differences between methods and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529184/difference-between-method-and-function-in-scala).

Comment: You cannot obtain a reference to the function `f`, because there is no function `f` in your code. There is only a method `f`, which is something completely different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're calling a function that has no parameters, then you can drop the brackets. That's why `f` evaluates to 1.

The exact same expression can also evaluate into a function reference if the compiler knows that you're expecting a value of that type.

```
val foo: () => Int = f
```

Answer (score 3):

You can obtain so using _ :

```
  var y = 0
  def m:Int = {y + 1}
  val result = m _  // type of result is an instance of Function0 "() => Int"
```

Use _ when compiler is not expecting Function object.

Comment: I get a Eta-expansion of zero-argument method values is deprecated with this.

Comment: @Rpant Which Scala version are you using?

Comment: @Rpant I am not getting any such error or warning with Scala "2.12.7".

Comment: @Rpant I tried and it is not giving any warning/error at https://scastie.scala-lang.org/

Comment: I still get the error , but going by the warning i mentioned above , i removed the empty parameter and the eta expansion worked. `var y = 0;
def m = {y + 1};
val resultingFunction = m _;
resultingFunction`;

Answer (score 2):

If you want `f` to be an expression of type `() => Int` that evaluates to `{ y + 1 }`, then just define it as such:

```
var y = 0
val f: () => Int = () => { y + 1 }
```

Now

```
f
```

does nothing (it just gives back the lambda of type `() => Int`), but

```
f()
```

gives `1`.

You don't really need the type ascription, this works too:

```
val f = () => { y + 1 }
```